# Does SSLv3 uses SHA256 as hashing algorithm?

Tags: tls, openssl

I understand that SSLv3 has multiple cipher suite combinations and for hashing it may use either SHA or MD5. What version of SHA does it exactly use SHA-0 or SHA-1 or SHA-2 (SHA256, SHA512 etc)..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLS 1.0 (SSLv3 successor) was published in January 1999 ([RFC 2246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246)). SHA-2 was first published in FIPS 180-2 in 2001. Thus, there's no way an implementation following just the SSL3 specifications could have supported SHA-2.

The version used by SSLv3 would have been SHA-1, just like TLS 1.0:

```
SHA
   The Secure Hash Algorithm is defined in FIPS PUB 180-1. It
   produces a 20-byte output. Note that all references to SHA
   actually use the modified SHA-1 algorithm. [SHA]
```

[rfc2246 page 59](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246#page-59)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Angel. Just to confirm once again, you meant SSLv3 doesn't support SHA-2?

Comment: @Aaron88  From a security perspective, SHA-1 vs SHA2 in this context is irrelevant.  It's everything else in SSLv3 that should make you want to scream and burn it with fire.

Answer (score 1):

Though @Angel's answer is mostly correct, there can be *details*...

In the SSL family of protocols (a family which includes [SSL 3.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101), as well as [TLS 1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246), [TLS 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346) and [TLS 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246)), there are about four places where a hash function may be used:

- In the "PRF", which is the function used for key derivation during the handshake and other similar usages. In SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1, the PRF uses MD5 and SHA-1, exclusively (SSL 3.0's PRF is distinct from the one used in TLS 1.0 and 1.1). In TLS 1.2, the PRF uses a hash function that depends on the cipher suite, usually SHA-256.
- For integrity protection of records, normally as part of HMAC (in TLS variants) or sort-of-HMAC (in SSL 3.0). This is defined by the cipher suite. Cipher suites are, by definition, open-ended: new cipher suites can be defined long after the base protocol has been standardized. For instance, [RFC 5487](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5487) defines some cipher suites in a "pre-shared key" model, and that use HMAC/SHA-256 for integrity; that RFC explicitly states that some of these suites (the ones that rely on AES in CBC mode for encryption) are applicable to previous versions of TLS (1.0 and 1.1). Technically, these cipher suites also apply to SSL 3.0.

  Note that SSL 3.0 is defined only in an "historic" RFC, not a "standard", which makes it somewhat difficult to talk about what can and cannot be done in SSL 3.0.
- As part of signatures on certificates. Existing, deployed implementations of SSL 3.0 (e.g. the one in Windows / Internet Explorer) will gleefully process certificates signed with RSA+SHA-256, even as part of a handshake that proceeds along the SSL 3.0 protocol version.
- In extensions. SSL 3.0 properly said (with the caveats explained above) does not define any extension, but it leaves room for them. Precisely, RFC 6101 says in section 5.6.1.2:

  ```
   Forward compatibility note: In the interests of forward
   compatibility, it is permitted for a client hello message to include
   extra data after the compression methods.  This data must be included
   in the handshake hashes, but must otherwise be ignored.
  ```

  Thus, while an SSL 3.0 implementation would be "justified" in ignoring any post-SSL-3.0 extension in the `ClientHello`, this does not prevent such extensions from appearing and possibly using SHA-256. Since SSL 3.0 is not actually a "standard", SSL 3.0 implementations may also choose to honour such extensions. One particular extension that may use SHA-256 is [session tickets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077), by which the server offloads the state of a session onto the client. In order to protect itself against malicious clients, the session ticket will normally be encrypted and integrity protected; RFC 5077 includes a [recommended ticket construction](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077#section-4) method that, indeed, relies on HMAC/SHA-256 for integrity.

**Summary:** while SSL 3.0 was defined way before SHA-256, and thus cannot inherently rely on SHA-256, there are several ways in which some SHA-256 crept its way into SSL 3.0. Maybe more relevant is the fact that there is no standard way to remove MD5 or SHA-1 from SSL 3.0, since they are part of the PRF -- but there again, SSL 3.0 is not a standard anyway. SSL 3.0 is only *what Netscape was doing at that time*.

Comment: At a time after sha256 was defined, why would someone choose to add support for a feature that uses sha256 to sslv3 instead saying that feature is only available in tls 1.0 and up?